# Объясните почему код выводит 1 , а не 10?

Tags: javascript

Наткнулся на задачу и не могу найти более подробного ответа.

```js
let a = 1;
function b() {
    a = 10;
    return;
    function a() {
        
    }
}
b();
console.log(a);
```

Почему консоль выводит 1.
Ведь идет изменение значения внешней переменной внутри функции.

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что _идет изменение значения внешней переменной внутри функции_?

Comment: Как я знаю Функция обладает полным доступом к внешним переменным и может изменять их значение. Поправьте если это не так

Comment: Это не отвечает на вопрос поставленный в предыдущем комментарии :-)

Comment: наличие `function a(){}` внутри `b()` не наталкивает ни на какие мысли, интересно?

Comment: внутри функции не создается локальная переменная (a = 10) а значит используется внешняя. При этом функция вызывается до консоли а не после

Comment: можно еще вывести `console.log(a)` перед изменением значения

Comment: _внутри функции не создается локальная переменная_ - и это главная ошибка в рассуждениях.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В данном случае внутри функции `b` описана функция `a`, которая, благодаря [*function declaration hoisting*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#function_declaration_hoisting) поднимается вверх.

Таким образом любое обращение к индентификатору `a`, внутри функции `b`, будет обращением к внутренней функции, а не глобальной переменной.

Проверить это можно, просто выведя значение `a`

```js
let a = 1;

function b() {
  console.log(a);
  return;
  function a() { }
}
b();
console.log(a);
```

Comment: Я бы еще присваивание `a=10` оставил  и после этого тоже бы в консоль вывел, для полноты картины.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko. ну в данном случае это не существенно, так как и так видно, что переменная совсем другая

Comment: Да, не существенно, но нагляднее получилось бы.